# Client-side signing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I found following in the Composer docs. Is it ok? I thought that CA is for storing certificates/public keys but not private keys. Is it possible to sign messages on a client-side?

> The Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority generates an enrollment secret that can be given to the participant, who can then use the enrollment secret to request their enrollment certificate and private keys from the Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority.

Comment: Yes its possible. Composer stores the key/certificate in a wallet accessible by the client application user, so the user can sign transactions on the business network (using a Composer business network card to connect to it and which has the user's blockchain identity). This transaction is therefore signed by a certificate to say which identity is being used to submit the transaction.

Comment: Composer is not running client side. The client would still need to trust the server running the composer service ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Composer stores the key/certificate in a wallet accessible by the client application user, so the user can sign transactions on the business network (using a Composer business network card to connect to it and which has the user's blockchain identity). This transaction is therefore signed by a certificate to say which identity is being used to submit the transaction.